# Fill missing values in selected columns with filtered values in other column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, null, fillna

I have a weird column named `null` in a dataframe that contains some missing values from other columns. One column is lat-lon coordinates named `location`, the other is an integer representing a target variable named `level`. In some but not all of the cases where `location` or `level` have missing values, the values that should be there are in this `null` column. Here's an example df:

```
pd.DataFrame(
     {'null': {0: '43.70477575,-72.28844073', 1: '2', 2: '43.70637091,-72.28704334', 3: '4', 4: '3'},
     'location': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
     'level': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}
     }
)
```

I need to be able to filter the `null` column according to whether the value is an integer or a string, and then based on that fill the missing value in the appropriate column with the appropriate value. I've tried using `.apply()` with a lambda funcation as well as `.match()`, `.contains()` and `in` inside of a for loop with no luck so far.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: I need to be able to filter the null column according to whether the value is an integer or a string, and then based on that, fill it in for a missing value in the appropriate column (strings in 'location' and integers in 'level').

Comment: Check my answer ,let me known if it is work ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest, if not the simplest approach, is to simply fill all the missing values in `df.location` and `df.level` with the values in `df.null`, then create a boolean filter with regex to return innappropriate/misassigned values in `df.location` and `df.level` to `np.nan`.

### pd.fillna()

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
     {'null': {0: '43.70477575,-72.28844073', 1: '2', 2: '43.70637091,-72.28704334', 3: '4', 4: '3'},
     'location': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
     'level': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}
     }
)

for col in ['location', 'level']:
     df[col].fillna(
          value = stress.null,
          inplace = True
     )
```

Now we'll use string expressions to correct the mis-assigned values.

### str.contains()

```
# Converting columns to type str so string methods work
df = df.astype(str)

# Using regex to change values that don't belong in column to NaN
regex = '[,]'
df.loc[df.level.str.contains(regex), 'level'] = np.nan
    
regex = '^\d\.?0?$'
df.loc[df.location.str.contains(regex), 'location'] = np.nan
    
# Returning `df.level` to float datatype (str is the correct
# datatype for `df.location`
df.level.astype(float)
```

Here's the output:

```
pd.DataFrame(
     {'null': {0: '43.70477575,-72.28844073', 1: '2', 2: '43.70637091,-72.28704334', 3: '4', 4: '3'},
      'location': {0: '43.70477575,-72.28844073', 1: nan, 2: '43.70637091,-72.28704334', 3: nan, 4: nan},
      'level': {0: nan, 1: '2', 2: nan, 3: '4', 4: '3'}
     }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `to_numeric`

```
checker = pd.to_numeric(df.null, errors='coerce')
checker
Out[171]: 
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    4.0
4    3.0
Name: null, dtype: float64
```

And apply `isnull`, if return `NaN` mean that is string not int

```
isstring = checker.isnull()
Out[172]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: null, dtype: bool
# isnumber = checker.notnull()
```

Fill value

```
df.loc[isnumber, 'location'] = df['null']
df.loc[isstring, 'level'] = df['null']
```

Comment: This code can filter the null column for integers, but it doesn't fill the missing values in the level column with those values.

Comment: @KristianCanler you can fill with above condition also check the update

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might use the method `pandas.Series.mask`:

```
>>> df
                       null  location  level
0  43.70477575,-72.28844073       NaN    NaN
1                         2       NaN    NaN
2  43.70637091,-72.28704334       NaN    NaN
3                         4       NaN    NaN
4                         3       NaN    NaN
>>> df.level.mask(df.null.str.isnumeric(), other = df.null, inplace = True)
>>> df.location.where(df.null.str.isnumeric(), other = df.null, inplace = True)
>>>
>>> df
                       null                  location level
0  43.70477575,-72.28844073  43.70477575,-72.28844073   NaN
1                         2                       NaN     2
2  43.70637091,-72.28704334  43.70637091,-72.28704334   NaN
3                         4                       NaN     4
4                         3                       NaN     3
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html

Comment: Sorry, I needed to update the dataframe! That was an edited version. I've got the correct one in the OP now.

Comment: When I implement this code, it appears that it fills some strings into df.level, which needs to be all integers.